# dynamically updating jquery tab number to reflect row number called by php loop

Tags: jquery, widget

I'm working through a project and am using jquery to build tabs that will contain form elements (not sure if it's possible but trying).

Using the tab widget, is there a way to set the tab number for each row called up dynamically with a for loop?

ETA: I think I am supposed to edit to add another part of  the question instead of asking a new one? 
I am really close to getting this to work, but despite spending the past few hours reading documentation and trying different things out, I just can't seem to quite get there. Could I get some help learning how to format this?

I thought I could do load: but it doesn't quite work. I am pretty sure that I (finally) have the php code formatted properly to return the results that will show the tabbed elements, but viewing the code I definitely don't have it typed properly because it still doesn't give me the tab number. I don't know if I'm referencing the tab number function incorrectly, or writing the function incorrectly, or both.

TIA for any advice!

```
<script>

    $(function() {

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({

            load: function numTabs(){
               i = 0;
                       $('.ui-tabs-nav li').each(function(){

                          $(this).children('a').prepend(i + '.');
                          i++;
            });
    }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here is the html/php:

```
<?php
include_once('dbxxx.php');
$conn = new DatabaseConn();

$query = "SELECT xxx_id, xxx_name FROM xxxor ORDER BY xxx_id";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result){

    echo '<div id="tabs"><ul><br />';

$numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);

$data = array();

$flist = array();

for($i=0;$i<$numfields;$i++)$flist[] = mysql_field_name($result,$i);

        $data[0] = $flist;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $data[] = $row;

        echo '<li><a href="#tabs-'.$numTabs.'"><input type="hidden" value="'. $row['xxx_id'] .'" />' . $row['xxx_name'] . '</a></li>';

    $query2 = "SELECT zzz_id, zzz_name FROM zzzce ORDER BY zzz_id";

    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

    if($result2){

        echo '<div id="tabs-'.$numTabs.'">';

        $numzzz = mysql_num_fields($result2);

        $data2 = array();

        $flist2 = array();

        for($j=0;$j<$numzzz;$j++)$flist2[] = mysql_field_name($result2,$j);

        $data2[0] = $flist2;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){

            $data2[] = $row;

            echo '
            <input type="checkbox" value="'. $row['zzz_id'] .'" />' . $row['zzz_name'] . '';
            }
            echo '<br /></div>';
    }
    }

echo '</ul></div><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through them:

```
function numTabs(){
    i = 1;
    $('.ui-tabs-nav li').each(function(){
       $(this).children('a').prepend(i + '.');
       i++;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need a little help understanding this better, sorry! I'll continue to read the documentation to try to find the answer but have been looking/reading/testing for a couple of hours now and want to ask rather than keep banging my head against the wall...

Comment: Can you let me know a little bit more about what you're stuck on?

Comment: Am I calling the variable incorrectly in the php echo? The code is clearly trying to format it properly, but view-source reveals that each tab is called #tab-2 instead of different tab numbers.

Comment: I don't know if you'd be willing to send me the link, but at this point it's hard to say without seeing the rendered code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

$(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        load: function(){
           i = 0;
           $('.ui-tabs-nav li').each(function(){
             $(this).children('a').prepend(i + '.');
             i++;
           });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

You had the numTabs() function name in there, but it's not needed since you're already invoking an action. Also you had an extra '}'.

Comment: If my code already references the i(and a j) in my php loops- do I have to either a. match the letter of the loop this is for, b. use the next (k) or c. it doesn't matter because one is javascript and one is php?

Comment: Variables in PHP won't affect those in the JavaScript

Comment: Thank you @Fluidbyte , that is helpful to know. Maybe I'm missing something else then; but my debugger isn't picking up any code errors.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but I put together a demo on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/McJsn/

Comment: It theoretically helps since it shows me that I'm most likely doing this correctly- but I am getting stuck at the fact that the <li> items are dynamically generated... I was indicating the code as <a href="#tab-'. $i .'"> but I am wondering if that's not correct since that's how I call the php variable.